# How to write the "subtitle" like this?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I want to write some `subtitle` like the bold sentence inside the box, could anyone give me some guide on how to do it? Basically this `subtitle` is inside a `section` environment.

I have no idea how to write this `subtitle`, as well as how to generate the `box`. Could anyone give me some help? Thx.

[image]

Comment: Could we consider it's a subsection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); there are two commands `\FramedSections` and `\RegularSections` that can be used as many times as required in the doucument to switch to framed or unframed subsections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\newcommand\RegularSections{
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{##1}
}
\newcommand\FramedSections{
\titleformat{\subsection} 
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,colback=white,left=1pt,right=1pt,nobeforeafter]\thesubsection. ##1\end{tcolorbox}}
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless} 
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,colback=white,left=1pt,right=1pt,nobeforeafter]##1\end{tcolorbox}}
}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
  {0pt}{1.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\subsection{A test numbered regular section title}
Some test text
\FramedSections
\subsection{A test numbered framed section title}
Some test text
\subsection*{A test unnumbered framed section title}
Some test text
\RegularSections
\subsection{A test numbered regular section title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

If what you need is a framed numbered box with some text in it, independent from the sectional units.  then you can simply use `tcolorbox` to build the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{MyTCBFramedTitle}{
  oversize,
  colback=white,
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt,
  fontupper=\large\bfseries,
  }
\newcommand\MyFramedTitle[1]{%
  \begin{MyTCBFramedTitle}
  \thetcbcounter.\hspace{0.5em}#1
  \end{MyTCBFramedTitle}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A test numbered section title}
Some test text
\MyFramedTitle{A test framed title}
Some test text
\MyFramedTitle{Another test framed title}
Some test text
\section{Another test numbered section title}
Some test text
\MyFramedTitle{Yet another test framed title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Gonzalo, thank you a lot for your advice. But is there any way not "pollute" the original `section` macro..? thank you!

Comment: @computeresdy What does the counter for the title reprsent? Is it a subsection counter, a user defined counter? Should this new command behave as a sectional unit command? Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This should be a subsection counter.

Comment: @computereasy Just to be sure, do you want the frames for *all* subsectons or just for some of them?

Comment: Just some of them.

Comment: @computereasy Please see my updated answer. Now you have the possibility to have framed and unframed subsection as many times as required.

Comment: @computereasy I am still confused, however, do you meant subsection as in the sectional unit \subsection or do you just want some numbered box with the text independently of the sectional unit?

Comment: @computereasy Nevermind. I added this option too in my updated answer. Now you have framed numbered boxes without relation to the sectional unit commands, in case that was what you were after.