# How to achieve round cornered frame in titlesec package

Tags: titlesec, rounded-corners

Not duplicate of :[How to write the "subtitle" like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266002)
The above question wanted some of the subsections round corner framed. The answer provided requires a command which almost behaves like an environment.

Here the answer requires solution which can manipulate `subsection` command globally and with less dependencies.
This is my example:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%%%%subsection title formating%%%%%%
\titleformat{\subsection}[frame]
{\filcenter\bfseries\Large}{}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{this section doesnt need box}
\subsection{This subsection needs round corner box}
This can be normal paragraph. This can be normal paragraph. This can be normal paragraph. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The question is still effectively a duplicate. You don't need to use the environment in the question, just use the framed  formatting for your subsection using the commands in the answer.  If  you're having problems with the code, edit your question using your modified version of that code.

Comment: You will need to change `##1` to `#1` in the `titlesec` commands when you remove them from inside the `\FramedSections` command.

Comment: I used this format `\titleformat{\subsection} 
[block]
  {\filcenter\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,colback=white,left=1pt,right=1pt,nobeforeafter]}[\end{tcolorbox}]` by using `block` option instead of `frame` we can escape problems with vertical mode.